# Why does my code not run even after pressing ctrl + s (Save)?

Tags: javascript

Recently I was coding in JS and in my browser, looking at my JS through it. When i saved my code nothing ran as it should.

What I have tried: I have tried re-coding this code and yet still it is not running as intended.

**The code:**

```js
var day1 = prompt(" Distance on Day-1 in km");
var day2 = prompt(" Distance on Day-2 in km");
var day3 = prompt(" Distance on Day-3 in km");
var SumOfDays = day1 + day2 + day3;
```

Comment: You need to tell what "not running as intended" means. Does it not do anything? Or does it do something but not what you wanted? Errors in the console?

Comment: The code does nothing yet no console errors

Comment: 1. You need to console.log(SumOfDays) to see anything 2. You need to cast the strings prompt returns to numbers: `var SumOfDays = +day1 + +day2 + +day3; console.log(SumOfDays);` Also the code needs to be inside `<script></script>` in your html page

Comment: It's probably asking for the distances. But not printing anything after that? That's because you didn't do anything with SumOfDays. Just add a line `alert(SumOfDays)` at the end.

Comment: Thanks, but I have been doing that code for a while with no reason to use console.log() and I have done number 2 even before asking the question, otherwise I would not be asking

Comment: `no reason to use console.log` ??? How do you show the result? Where is the rest of the code?

Comment: I do not know, I have been coding through a course on Udemy and the teacher has never used it on a video and his code still works, all I have been doing is following along as I am fairly new to coding

Comment: Thanks for responding everyone! In the time that this question has been up I have been able to get the code up and running like it should.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what do you actually mean.

If you simply want to run your code in browser, connect your JavaScript with HTML.

```
<script src="myscripts.js"></script>
```

Put this into the `<head>` of your HTML and then open the HTML file.

Comment: @NewDev did you try to put this into <body> ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just defining variables.
No action yet.
Try to output something to the console with console.log
See the result.